# Implode array from static properties?

Tags: php, arrays, properties, static, refactoring

I have a class with two static properties.

`$statuses` is an array with the status id and their string values for display.

`$status_changes` is an array of the current status id and the value is an array of allowed status changes.

```
class Status {
    public static $statuses = [
        1 => 'Box Stock',
        11 => 'Box Stock (Refurbished)',
        2 => 'Transit',
        3 => 'Active',
        4 => 'Inactive',
        12 => 'RMA Authorized',
        5 => 'RMA',
        6 => 'Scrap',
        8 => 'Customer Spare',
        9 => 'Consigned',
        13 => 'Holding',
        10 => 'Internal Use',
        7 => 'Unknown'
    ];

    public static $status_changes = [
        1 => [2, 3, 10, 13],
        11 => [2, 10, 13],
        2 => [3, 10, 12, 13],
        3 => [4],
        4 => [3, 6, 7, 11, 12],
        12 => [5, 6, 11],
        5 => [6, 11],
        6 => [7],
        8 => [3],
        9 => [3, 8],
        13 => [3, 8],
        10 => [3, 6, 11],
        7 => [6, 11]
    ];

    function echoAllowed($status) {
        echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($s) { 
            return Status::$statuses[$s]; 
        },
        self::$status_changes[$status]));
    }
}

$s = new Status();
$s->echoAllowed(1);
// Should print "Transit, Active, Internal Use, Holding".
```

What is the best way to implode the list of allowed status changes, given a status id? (As I've done in the `echoAllowed()` method.)

Comment: Well you got it right, you ask for an optimized way?

Comment: @vuryss Yes, I'd like to know if this is the cleanest solution or not.

Comment: I personaly would not use the `echo` inside the class, but refactor that method to return a string (or array of strings: `['Transit','Active','']`) and then call `echo $s->getAllowedStatuses()` or respectively `echo implode(', ', $s->getAllowedStatuses())`

Comment: As @Dragos quite rightly said, return the value from the class inside an object. I would also set the array properties to `private` so you can only access them within the class.

Comment: @Dragos I don't actually have it echoing in the class. I dumbed it down for the example. The class is using the string to create a message saying what statuses the user is allowed to change.